# How can I define a new C++ type conversion so that libpqxx will know how to convert that type?

Tags: c++, windows, postgresql, libpqxx

Stuff Used:

1. Windows                                            10
2. libpq:x64-windows                                  9.6.1-7
3. libpqxx:x64-windows                                6.4.4
4. MSVC Compiler

My Code:

```
#include <pqxx/pqxx>
#include <array>


struct Hand
{
    std::string GameType;
    int64_t TotalSize{};
    char Currency{};
    int16_t MaxHeight{};
    std::array<std::string, 5> Apple;
    bool Foo = false;
};


int main() {

    //Connect possible trycatch
    pqxx::connection  database_connection("dbname = blablabla user = postgres password = blablabla\
      hostaddr = 127.0.0.1 port = 5432");

    //Prepare Insert
    database_connection.prepare("Hand_Insert", "INSERT INTO Hand(GameType, TotalSize, Currency, MaxHeight, Apple, Foo) VALUES\
        VALUES($1, $2,$3, $4,$5::text[3],$6)");


    Hand hand;
    hand.Currency = '$';
    hand.Apple.at(0) = "value1";
    hand.Apple.at(1) = "value2";
    hand.Apple.at(2) = "value3";
    hand.Foo = true;
    hand.GameType = "TestType";
    hand.MaxHeight = 7;
    hand.TotalSize = 300;


    pqxx::work work(database_connection);
    try
    {
        pqxx::result result = work.exec_prepared("Hand_Insert", hand.GameType, hand.TotalSize, hand.Currency, hand.MaxHeight, hand.Apple, hand.Foo);
        work.commit();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
        work.abort();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the Output:

```
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(192,29): error C2027:  use of undefined type 'pqxx::string_traits<Arg,void>'
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(192,29): error C2027:         with
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(192,29): error C2027:         [
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(192,29): error C2027:             Arg=char
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(192,29): error C2027:         ]
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(192): message :  see declaration of 'pqxx::string_traits<Arg,void>'
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(192): message :         with
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(192): message :         [
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(192): message :             Arg=char
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(192): message :         ]
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(212): message :  see reference to function template instantiation 'void pqxx::internal::params::add_field<char>(const Arg &)' being compiled
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(212): message :         with
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(212): message :         [
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(212): message :             Arg=char
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(212): message :         ]
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(212): message :  see reference to function template instantiation 'void pqxx::internal::params::add_fields<char&,int16_t&,std::array<std::string,5>&,bool&>(Arg,int16_t &,std::array<std::string,5> &,bool &)' being compiled
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(212): message :         with
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(212): message :         [
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(212): message :             Arg=char &
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(212): message :         ]
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(212): message :  see reference to function template instantiation 'void pqxx::internal::params::add_fields<int64_t&,char&,int16_t&,std::array<std::string,5>&,bool&>(Arg,char &,int16_t &,std::array<std::string,5> &,bool &)' being compiled
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(212): message :         with
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(212): message :         [
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(212): message :             Arg=int64_t &
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(212): message :         ]
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(111): message :  see reference to function template instantiation 'void pqxx::internal::params::add_fields<std::string&,int64_t&,char&,int16_t&,std::array<std::string,5>&,bool&>(Arg,int64_t &,char &,int16_t &,std::array<std::string,5> &,bool &)' being compiled
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(111): message :         with
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(111): message :         [
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(111): message :             Arg=std::string &
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(111): message :         ]
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\transaction_base.hxx(397): message :  see reference to function template instantiation 'pqxx::internal::params::params<std::string&,int64_t&,char&,int16_t&,std::array<std::string,5>&,bool&>(std::string &,int64_t &,char &,int16_t &,std::array<std::string,5> &,bool &)' being compiled
1>C:\Users\Vaio\source\repos\Project3\Project3\Source.cpp(42): message :  see reference to function template instantiation 'pqxx::result pqxx::transaction_base::exec_prepared<std::string&,int64_t&,char&,int16_t&,std::array<std::string,5>&,bool&>(const std::string &,std::string &,int64_t &,char &,int16_t &,std::array<std::string,5> &,bool &)' being compiled
1>C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pqxx\internal\statement_parameters.hxx(192,1): error C3861:  'is_null': identifier not found
1>Done building project "Project3.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

How can I define a new C++ type conversion so that libpqxx will know how to convert that type?

Or if the error is something else anything will help!